# How can I loop through a SQL script with distinct rows found in a particular column (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-loop, while-loop

I am attempting to build a report that performs a few calculations (35 calculations) and have that script iterate over the total number of distinct locations in a specified column. I would like it to build a report for each distinct location which are stored in a separate column.

Is there a way to do this in SQL or am I going to have to do this with python or another language?

This is a simplified main query I want to iterate, with the 'XXXXXXXX' in the where statement to change respectively. There is a column in DataTable2 called locationid which houses 43 distinct locations which I would like to iterate through.

```
SELECT Procedure, 
       Count(case when patienttype = 'Inpatient'then caseid end) AS [IP Volume],
       Count(case when patienttype = 'Outpatient' then caseid end) AS [OP Volume],
       Avg(case when patienttype = 'Inpatient' then los end) AS [LOS],
From DataTable2
Where location = 'XXXXXXXX'
```

Is this possible in SQL server 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `group by`:

```
select location, Procedure, 
       Count(case when patienttype = 'Inpatient'then caseid end) AS [IP Volume],
       Count(case when patienttype = 'Outpatient' then caseid end) AS [OP Volume],
       Avg(case when patienttype = 'Inpatient' then los end) AS [LOS],
from DataTable2
group by location, Procedure
order by location, Procedure;
```

Comment: Essentially, I want each location to be on its own page, which is why I initially was thinking of a for loop. But I suppose I can make a VBA script to parse out every new location onto its own sheet. Unless there are other opinions on how to break out the report.

Answer (score 1):

Use distinct on the column and then group by?